# NetAdvantage_NET_20081_CLR20_Product.exe : Installation ended prematurely because of an error

Tags: installation, infragistics, virtual-directory, netadvantage

I am stuck on installing this netadvantage ASP.NET feature even though I was able to install the sdk and the NetAdvantage_20111 and the infragistics professional 2019 Vol1.
The problem rise when the installer reaches the step 'Creating Virtual Directory' ig_common/20081CLR20/Forms/WebSchedule. It cannot go further and starts rolling back the installation and finally get a 'installation ended prematurely because of an error'.

I tried to follow the steps advised to fix this error here but nothing works.
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/installation-fails-installation-ended-prematurely-because-of-an-error/

I also tried to grant full control to anyone to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client with no success.

The installation of 20111CLR20 in this directory went symlessly though.

I also tried to follow the above steps with the Administrator account.

Any idea?

Comment: I can add that the os is a win10 pro 64 bits running as an hyper-v second generation client

Comment: Try to use the Event viewer to check the Windows logs. Perhaps the logs contain some additional error description that can help to investigate the problem.